# Laravel4 - Controller method not found

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

Im having some problems on the production version when adding new methods to the controller it seems like it dosent update the controller or has some kind of controllers cache

Already tried php composer.phar dump-autoload, php artisan dump-autoload, php artisan optimize, doing composer.json psr-0 did nothing:

```
"psr-0": {
   "Fideloper": "app/"
}
```

also tried changing method name.

this is how I have the route and method:

Routes in route.php

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'users'), function(){
     Route::get('/', array('as' => 'experts', 'uses' => 'Controllers\Admin\UserController@getExperts' ));

}
```

Method in Controllers\Admin\UserController

```
public function getExperts()
{
       // return experts listObject
}
```

Thanks in advance (this is driving me crazy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the composer.json part you have provided and the route part, you have a folder structure like this

```
app/
--Fideloper/
  --Controllers/
    --Admin/
```

So in the route you have to specify the full namespace of the controller

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'users'), function(){
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'experts', 'uses' => 'Fideloper\Controllers\Admin\UserController@getExperts' ));
}
```

Comment: thanks but what if i dont want to use composer.json autoload my controllers

Comment: if you don't put controllers in the provided default folder you have to tell composer how to load them. if you look at composer.json under the classmap section you will see that the laravel creators have added the pat app/controllers to the autoload, so if you use a different folder you have to tell to composer!

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding Fed03, but I already have many controllers working in the default Controller directory (production /development enviroment) the doubt is if theres something to update because it dosent detects new methods, I tried using the psr-0 but is now discarted

Comment: Could not found a way to solve this issue, its currently working now but what I did is compressed all the development site and moved to production, probably the best way is using a Deployment to avoid this. But I still wonder how could I solve this issue, I have seen a lot of posts that talk about this but nobody gives an answer that I can apply.

Found this article css-tricks.com/deployment/ where it explains some methods to do this.